# Difference between $\operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z$ and $\operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z\left[\frac1n\right]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

> What is the difference between the affine schemes, $\operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z$ and $\operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z\left[\frac1n\right]$ ?

I know the spectrum of a ring is the set of its prime ideals, but when the ring is enlarged does its spectrum shrink down (always)?

Can we say if $X$ is a $\operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z[\frac1n]$ scheme then it is also a $Spec\mathbb Z$ scheme ?

Comment: And just to be clear, because the answer below doesn't explicitly state it, recall that the underlying set of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$ consists of $(0)$ and $(p)$ for all prime numbers $p$. $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z[1/n]$ throws out all $(p)$ such that $p$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding a ring doesn't always mean shrinking the associated some schemes. However, expanding a ring by specifically adding inverses of elements that didn't already have inverses will shrink the Spec space. The inclusion $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z[1/n]$ will induce an inclusion $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z[1/n]\subseteq \operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$.

In contrast, $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$ is well-known and easy to describe, while $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z[X]$ is a complicated beast, and I don't think we are anywhere near a description of $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z[X,Y]$.

If you have two rings $R, S$ and a ring homomorphism $R\to S$, then that induces a morphism of affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec}S\to\operatorname{Spec}R$. And if $X$ is a $\operatorname{Spec}S$ scheme, that just means there is a morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec}S$. Composing that with the morphism $\operatorname{Spec}S\to\operatorname{Spec}R$ gives you a morphism $X\to \operatorname{Spec}R$, which is to say that $X$ is indeed a scheme over  $\operatorname{Spec}R$. This is true for $R = \Bbb Z$ and $S = \Bbb Z[1/n]$ in particular.

There is a morphism from *any* scheme $X$ to $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$. It takes each point in $X$ to the (prime ideal generated by the) characteristic of the residue field over that point. So any scheme is a $\Bbb Z$-scheme.

Comment: so given any morphisms $A\to B$,$\ B\to C$ you can always compose them to $A\to C$

Comment: @counterfeit Yes, you can always compose morphisms. In category theory, that is one of the defining features of a morphism. In specific cases, though, morphisms are often functions or collections of functions, and those are clearly composeable as well.